# How can I regroup in a same class XmlArrayAttributes that are named differently?

Tags: c#, xml, backend

I have to deserialize an XML object that is made as follows :

```
<programs>
   <item0></item0>
   <item1></item1>
    ...
   <item200></item200>
</programs>
```

The fact is that the structure of each `<item></item>` is the same so I want to regroup all these items in a same C# class that would look like this :

```
public class Item{
    public object prop1{get; set; }
    public object prop2{get; set; }
    public object prop3{get; set; }
}
```

Instead of this, for now I've got this structure in C# :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="programs")]
public class Programs { 
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item0")] 
    public Item0 Item0 { get; set; } 
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item1")] 
    public Item1 Item1 { get; set; } 
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item2")] 
    public Item2 Item2 { get; set; }
    
    ...
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item200")] 
    public Item200 Item200 { get; set; }
}
```

If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ you can convert the XML to desired output

Say the given xml is in this format

```
<programs>
  <item0 attribute1="0">
    <property1>test1</property1>
  </item0>
  <item1 attribute1="1">
    <property1>test2</property1>
  </item1>
  <item200 attribute1="2">
    <property1>test3</property1>
  </item200>
</programs>
```

Have a Item class with defined elements

```
public class Items
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string attribute1 { get; set; }
}
```

Using LINQ you can filter all items and create desired object

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(strFile);
var result = xdoc.Descendants().Where(x=>x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("item")).Select(y=> new Items() {
    id = y.Name.LocalName.Replace("item",""),
    property1 = y.Element("property1").Value,
    attribute1 = y.Attribute("attribute1").Value
});
```